# PHP DOMElement replace string in text nodes with element

Tags: php, dom

I have a DOMElement of the following form:

`<text>This is some text with <i>some words in italics and <b>bold</b></i>.</text>`

I would like to wrap, in all the text nodes of this element, a certain string (say, "some") in another element (say, `<span></span>`). So the result should be:

`<text>This is <span>some</span> text with <i><span>some</span> words in italics and <b>bold</b></i>.</text>`

How can this be done? It should be assumed that the text nodes may be at an arbitrary depth.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's takes a bit of a hack, but with something along the lines below (adjusted for your actual html, rather than the one assumed below), you should get there.

```
$str = <<<XXX
<doc>
<div><text>This is some text with <i>some words in italics and <b>bold</b></i>.
</text>
</div>
</doc>
XXX;


$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);

#locate the existing DOMElement
$originalNode = $xpath->query('//text')[0];

#extract its innerHTML
$original_ih =  $originalNode->ownerDocument->saveHTML($originalNode);

#now the hack...
$temp = str_replace('words','xxxwordsxxx', $original_ih);
$sa = explode('xxx',$temp);
$final_ih = "{$sa[0]}<span>{$sa[1]}</span>{$sa[2]}";

#import the new innerHTML into the DOM:
$fragment = $xml->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($final_ih);

#replace the old with the new
$originalNode->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $originalNode);
echo $xml->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<doc>
<div><text>This is some text with <i>some <span>words</span> in italics and <b>bold</b></i>.
</text>
</div>
</doc>
```

EDIT:
To create a new document from the modified element:

```
$xml_new = new DOMDocument();
$xml_new->loadXML($final_ih);
echo $xml_new->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<text>This is some text with <i>some <span>words</span> in italics and <b>bold</b></i></text>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I have difficulty adapting your solution to my concrete situation. The situation is that the XML document from which the DOMElement is drawn is loaded earlier in the script. I tried to import the variable in which the XML is stored into the current function with `global`, but am receiving the following error: `Uncaught DOMException: Wrong Document Error`. I wonder whether it is possible to make the replacement in the DOMElement without reference to the XML document from which it is drawn.

Comment: @Wolfhart If I understand  you correctly (and I'm not sure I do), I don't know how you can do that. But how did you select the relevant DOMElement without reference to the XML doc in which it's contained?

Comment: Of course, I get my DOMElement from an XML document, like so: `$xml = new DOMDocument(); $xml->load('foo.xml'); $xpath = new DOMXpath($xml); $texts = $xpath->query("//text")`. This gives me a DOMNodeList. Now I want to loop through this list and make the said replacement in the DOMElements of the list. What I don't understand is why, in the code that makes the replacement, it is necessary to refer to the XML document from which the DOMNodeList is drawn. Is it not possible to manipulate just the DOMElements as I have them in the list, without consideration of the rest of the XML document?

Comment: @Wolfhart Well, unless you want to maintain the target element on a standalone basis (that is, effectively create a new document), by modifying an element in the document, you are modifying the whole document. And in this particular case, you aren't just modifying the text of an element, you are creating a brand new one and that has to be reinserted in the original document in place of the original element.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Yes, I would like to maintain the target element on a standalone basis. If I understand you correctly, that means that I need to transform the DOMElement into a DOMDocument. How do I do that?

Comment: @Wolfhart Yes, that's possible; see edit.

Comment: I am still struggling to get the code to work in my case. While I was struggling to understand the code, it occurred to me that the code will not always do what I want. If I understand correctly, the code will replace the search string not only in text elements, but also in tags. For example, if the DOMElement contains `<span>a span of words</span>` and I want to replace the word “span”, the given code will replace “span” not only in the text node, but also in the tags, which I do not want. Am I understanding correctly that this is what the code will do?

Comment: @Wolfhart Yes, I think it's possible. However, it's probably best (and required by SO) to  post it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, I did post it as a separate question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71446810/php-dom-wrap-search-string-in-text-nodes-in-span-span)